# Angularfire show key and value

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In my angular project, I am using angularfirebase as below to save user displayname:

```
this.afDB.object('/users/' + this.userId).set({displayName: user.displayname })
```

Which gives something like this...

[image]

Then in order to display it, I am doing the following:

```
this.profileData = this.db.list(`/users/${this.userId}/`);
```

Then, in HTML:

```
<p> {{(profileData | async)?. displayName}} </p> <!-- Doesn't show any -->
```

However, it doesn't show any data.

If I try below, then it does show the user name:

```
<div class="text" *ngFor="let item of profileData| async">
     {{item.$value}} <!-- Shows the display name -->
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Since there is only one key, I don't need `*ngFor` and I am baffled. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I am simply trying to show the logged-in user display name by using `this.userId`. In this example, let say the logged-in user has id of "se5Zmy8n..." (the last one in the img). Then the `displayName` would be "asesdf4r".

Comment: With `<div class="text" *ngFor="let item of profileData| async">{{item.$value}}</div>`, I get `asesdf4r` as the result. With `<p> {{(profileData | async)?. displayName}} </p>`, just a blank. And no i am not using jquery. I have been on this issue for two days and it is driving me crazy lol.

Comment: Yeah,, nothing.. Just a blank.

Comment: Just shows as `[object Object]`. I looked at the `console.log` and just shows "FirebaseListObservable" (http://imgur.com/a/Cr2VW).

Comment: I know I am getting something since `{{item.$value}}` shows the right info. It's just pain in the arse to avoid using `*ngFor`.

Comment: Yes and no, for me it means that profileData doesn't have displayName attribute

Comment: Oh i see. I didn't think of that way. I may need to find out if `this.afDB.object('/users/' + this.userId).set({displayName: user.displayname })` is even correct. Thanks! I will do some more digging.

Answer (score 0):

You're access a leaf node.  You need to go one level up to access all users

```
this.profileData = this.db.list('/users/');
```

List will give you an object with keys that are your user keys.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, I am not trying to access all users, but a specific user (like a logged in user). For example, let say you log in, you simply want to show your displayname. Does that mean, I need to get all the user info?

Comment: I added an extra info for a clarification. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you don't need a ngFor loop then because what would you be looping over if its just one user?